# How to find the next occurence in textarea without exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, textarea

I've been working on project which finds the next occurrence by clicking on button  of specific word, but it keeps throwing exceptions ?!

```
public void highlightnext(JTextComponent textareafield,String pattern) {
    textareafield.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();
    //highlighting      
    try { 
        hilit = textarea.getHighlighter();
        painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(HILIT_COLOR);
        Document doc=textarea.getDocument();
        String area=doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
        if (pos>area.length())
            return;
        pos=(area.toUpperCase().indexOf(pattern.toUpperCase(),pos));
        pos=(area.toUpperCase().indexOf(pattern.toUpperCase(),pos+1));
        hilit.addHighlight(pos,pos+pattern.length(), painter);
        System.out.println(pos);                    
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception do you get?

Comment: javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Invalid start offset

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Usually you should get information about the occurrence of the error. For instance the line where it stucks.

Comment: The problem is in `getText` try to do, just for test, `doc.getText(0, 1);` is that worked ?

Comment: I guess it's this one if `(pos>area.length()) return;`. Try` if (pos + pattern.length() > area.length()) return;`

Comment: Your ideas don't work ..
okay.. How can I reach the end of the textarea without using scroll bars which means using code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
pos=(area.toUpperCase().indexOf(pattern.toUpperCase(),pos));
pos=(area.toUpperCase().indexOf(pattern.toUpperCase(),pos+1));
```

1. Don't convert the data to upper case each time that is not efficient. Convert the text once into a String and then use those two strings in your code.
2. Not sure why you have two statements. You only need one to do the search.
3. You need to check the value of "pos" to make sure it is not "-1"

Here is some example code. It finds all occurrences of the text:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextAndNewLinesTest extends JFrame
{
    public TextAndNewLinesTest()
        throws Exception
    {
        String text =
            "one two three four five\r\n" +
            "one two three four five\r\n" +
            "one two three four five\r\n" +
            "one two three four five\r\n" +
            "one two three four five\r\n";

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText(text);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textPane );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.cyan );


        String search = "three";
        int offset = 0;

        int length = textPane.getDocument().getLength();
        text = textPane.getDocument().getText(0, length);
            //text = textPane.getText();    

        while ((offset = text.indexOf(search, offset)) != -1)
        {
            try
            {
                textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + 5, painter); // background
                offset += search.length();
            }
            catch(BadLocationException ble) {}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new TextAndNewLinesTest();
        frame.setTitle("Text and New Lines - Problem");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize(400, 120);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If you only want to find one occurrence at a time, then basically you would change the "while" statement to an "if" statement.